# Can I keep Jaheira/Khalid and Montaron/Xzar from killing each other?

Tags: baldurs-gate

Eventually I want to have all my characters neutral or "better". However, I've just started and I'm stuck with what I've got for now or I'll get myself killed (especially since I'm a first level mage, I get killed easily). I've got high charisma, can I use it knock their heads together? I'd like to keep Montaron and Xzar, at least until we reach Nashkell. I'm inclined to keep Jaheira and Khalid at least until better good characters come along. We're in Beregost now (for the first time). If we abandon our quests here for now and high-tail it to Nashkell, can I keep them from killing each other?

Please be gentle with me, I'm new to RPG gaming, I'm kind of clueless.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. It's based on time spent in the party and, unless you spend ages grinding before Nashkel, you can complete the mines quest before they fight.

Once you reach Nashkel, you can replace one of the groups with Minsc & Dynheir.

Comment: Don't Minsc and Dynheir fight with Montaron and Xzar as well?

Comment: I think they have dialogue but none of it results in one group leaving or attacking the other. Aside from Monty & Xzar being evil, there are no problems keeping them in the same party.

Comment: @Studoku Yep, endless grinding seems to be my biggest problem. Even Jaheira started to scold me. We're in Nashkel now and Xzar is dead (I think I like him better that way).

Comment: Minsc and Dynaheir have a fight with a certain Red Wizard, not with Xzar and Montaron ;)